# How to fix "MaskedArrayFutureWarning" while using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the following error when I used matplotlib. I would like to know to fix this warning message. I tried to pass `axis = 0` in `plt.contourf()`, but it does not help.

Warning:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py:6385: MaskedArrayFutureWarning: In the future the default for ma.minimum.reduce will be axis=0, not the current None, to match np.minimum.reduce. Explicitly pass 0 or None to silence this warning.
  return self.reduce(a)
```

Code:

```
figT = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15)) # (width, height)
for i in range(n_cases):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i+1)
    plt.contourf(x, y, sess.run(T[:,:,i]), colorInterpolation, cmap=colorMap)
    plt.colorbar().ax.set_ylabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)', fontsize = set_fontSize)
    plt.xlabel('X Position', fontsize = set_fontSize)
    plt.ylabel('Y Position', fontsize = set_fontSize)
    plt.title("Case %d" % (i+1), fontsize = set_fontSize)
figT.savefig(dirFig+'T_results.png', format='png', dpi=set_dpi, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Could you show me how to fix it? I tried `plt.contourf(axis = 0)` but the warning is still there.

Comment: The code throwing the warning is called indirectly and seems to be in a lib. Make sure all your libs are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error when using matplotlib 1.5.3. After I issued below command:

```
conda update matplotlib
```

Matplotlib was updated to 2.0.2 and warning was gone.